# Unable to Debug when running UWP Apps in x86 emulators

Tags: warnings, win-universal-app, emulation

I try to run my UWP app in x86 platform in **Mobile Emulator 10.0.10586.0 WVGA 4 inch 512 MB** 
it shows a warning like the below screenshot,
[image: Warning]

Due to this, i was unable to debug and i was unable to get values in Immediate Window. Can you please give me a solution for this?

Thanks in advance,

Venkatesan R

Comment: Your title says you can't run the apps but they question says you can, there are just no symbols for the system, which are not needed for running. So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Thanks @SamiKuhmonen yes i will modify the title of the question, i need to skip this warning, my app is running but i was unable to debug it. i can't retrieve any information for the defined variables in my app.